# Are there any Network Monitoring Tools supporting Tunneling Protocols?

Tags: network-monitoring

Does anyone know a network monitoring tool which has support for tunneling protocols e.g. VxLAN and NVGRE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark should have this functionality.